# Is it possible for a WPF control to have an ActualWidth and ActualHeight if it has never been rendered?

Tags: wpf, 3d, wpf-controls, actualwidth, actualheight

I need a `Viewport3D` for the sole purpose of doing geometric calculations using `Petzold.Media3D.ViewportInfo`. I would prefer not to have to place it in a `Window` or otherwise render it.

I'm attempting to accomplish this by instantiating a `Viewport3D` and setting a few properties using the following C# method:

```
private Viewport3D CreateViewport(MainSettings settings)
{
    var cameraPosition = new Point3D(0, 0, settings.CameraHeight);
    var cameraLookDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, -1);
    var cameraUpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
    var camera = new PerspectiveCamera
    {
        Position = cameraPosition,
        LookDirection = cameraLookDirection,
        UpDirection = cameraUpDirection
    };
    var viewport = new Viewport3D
    {
        Camera = camera,
        Width = settings.ViewportWidth,
        Height = settings.ViewportHeight
    };
    return viewport;
}
```

Later, I'm attempting to use this viewport to convert the mouse location to a 3D location using this method:

```
public Point3D? Point2dToPoint3d(Point point)
{
    var range = new LineRange();
    var isValid = ViewportInfo.Point2DtoPoint3D(_viewport, point, out range);
    if (isValid)
        return range.PointFromZ(0);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. I think the reason is that the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the viewport are both zero (and these are read-only properties, so I can't set them manually). (Note: I have tested the exact same method with an actual rendered `Viewport3D`, and it worked fine, so I know the issue is not with my converter method.)

Any idea how I can get WPF to assign the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of a control based on the `Width` and `Height` settings?

I tried setting the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Left` and `Top`, respectively, and I also messed with the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`, but none of these properties had any effect on the `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN topic for the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) property:

> *This property is a calculated value based on other width inputs, and the layout system. The value is set by the layout system itself, **based on an actual rendering pass**, and may therefore lag slightly behind the set value of properties such as Width  that are the basis of the input change.*

So, this sounds like a rendering pass is necessary for the property to be set. However, you could try to call [`Measure(Size)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and then [`Arrange(Rect)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) to simulate the layout process. Maybe this is already sufficient.