# Wpf How to set Grid Column ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, grid, actualwidth

Is it generally possible in `Grid` control to set `ActualWidth` of `Column`? This property has only getter. May be there is other way to assign some value to it?

I can set `MinWidth`, can set `Width`, so I think it would be logical to have possibility to set `ActualWidth`.

Comment: Already have an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947729/is-it-possible-for-a-wpf-control-to-have-an-actualwidth-and-actualheight-if-it-h

Comment: "I can set MinWidth, can set Width, so I think it would be logical to have possibility to set ActualWidth". For what reason? `ActualWidth` is a read-only property.

Comment: @Clemens I wanna set width to `Grid` `Column` programmatically, nothing else.

Comment: Then why not set the `Width` property???

Comment: @Sivasubramanian Unfortunately, `Column` has no method like `Measure` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the column's `Width` property:

```
column.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```